# Corona SDK Listener function within an object

Tags: object, module, lua, coronasdk

Is it possible to put a listener function inside of an object module?

I have a Cloud class that implements a Display Object. Right now, the class only creates the image. I'd like it to also be in charge of its own listener event, so that I do not need to keep calling the addEventListener per object I spawn.

I've tried several variations, and I always end up with the listener function as nil. I've also tried splitting it out so that the addEventListener function is called in the main.

I'm starting to get the feeling that listener functions in objects aren't supported. Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach to this? Is what I'm asking feasible? And if yes, what am I doing wrong?

```
--
-- Cloud.lua
--

local Cloud = {}
local mtaCloud = { __index = cloud } -- metatable

local display = require "display" 

-- DOESN'T WORK
function Cloud.scroll( event )
  img.y = img.y - img.scrollSpeed
  if (img.y + img.contentWidth) < 0 then
    img.x = 0
    img:translate( math.random(1,_W), 1800  )
  end
end

function Cloud.New( strImage, intHeight, intWidth, intScrollSpeed)

  local image = display.newImageRect( strImage, intWidth, intHeight )
  image.anchorX = 0; image.anchorY = 0.5;
  image.x = _W/2; image.y = _H/2;
  image.scrollSpeed = 10
  image.enterFrame = scroll
  Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", scroll)

  local newCloud = {

    img = image

  }

return setmetatable( newCloud, mtaCloud )

end

return Cloud

-- main.lua (simplified)
local cloud = require "object.cloud"

function scene:create( event )
  local group = self.view
  cloud = cloud.New("img/cloud.png", 230, 140)
  group:insert(cloud.img)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to set listeners on objects, if you mean objects in the usual object-oriented programming sense discussed in [Chapter 16 of Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html).  It's a matter of getting the `self` references right.  I've included an implementation that works in this answer.

I'm not sure if you can do this on a DisplayObject, but that isn't what you were doing in your example either (the DisplayObject is your `image` not what is returned by your constructor `Cloud.New()`, which is table `newCloud`).

Here is one way to do it that works for sure.  Your `Cloud.lua` should have something like this (I've used ShapeObjects in this scratch implementation for testing; you would make changes to use your image assets):

```
-- Cloud.lua

local Cloud = {}

function Cloud:scroll()

    self.img.x = self.img.x + self.scrollSpeed
    if self.img.x >= display.contentWidth + self.img.contentWidth then
        self.img.x = - self.img.contentWidth
    end

end

function Cloud:enterFrame( event )
    self:scroll()
end

function Cloud:new( intHeight, intWidth, intScrollSpeed )

    local aCloud = {}

    local img = display.newRect( 0, 0, intWidth, intHeight )
    img:setFillColor( 1 )

    aCloud.img = img
    aCloud.scrollSpeed = intScrollSpeed
    aCloud.id = id

    setmetatable( aCloud, self )
    self.__index = self

    Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", aCloud )

    return aCloud

end

return Cloud
```

Notice the `setmetatable` **and** `self.__index = self` in the `Cloud:new()` function.  This is key.

I've used the "colon notation" in the function definitions (eg. `Cloud:new(...)` ) which is syntactic sugar for the "dot notation" you used in which the first argument to the function is `self` (eg. `Cloud.new( self, ...)` ).

Also, I am using an object (table) listener (not a function); on each `enterFrame` event, the Runtime will call the `enterFrame()` function if one exists for the object (i.e. is found in the specified table).

Assuming a file named "Cloud.lua" is found in the project subdirectory "objects", in your `scene`, you would have something like:

```
local cloud = require("objects.Cloud")

local maxScrollRate = 4
local cloud1 = cloud:new( 100, 50, 1 + math.random( maxScrollRate )  )
cloud1.img.x = 200
cloud1.img.y = 200
sceneGroup:insert(cloud1.img)

local cloud2 = cloud:new( 100, 50, 1 + math.random( maxScrollRate ) )
cloud2.img.x = 100
cloud2.img.y = 400
sceneGroup:insert(cloud2.img)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm new to Lua (Mostly C# background) and it really helped me figure things out. One thing I got stuck on was with collisions - until I figured out that Cloud:new does not return the DisplayObject (which is the object that collisions happen on) :-D so it helps to add a img.super = aCloud line somewhere before the metadata stuff